# Подключить файл из корня wordpress в файле темы

Tags: wordpress

Допустим изменим атрибут `action` у формы комментариев, передав в массив аргументов функции `comment_form()` следующий ключ со значением:
 `'action'     => get_template_directory_uri() .  '/lib/wp-comments-post.php'`
далее скопируем файл `wp-comments-post.php` из корня сайта в каталог `lib` нашей темы, для дальнейшей правки (что-бы не править оригинал). 
Там есть строчка: `require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );`, которая говорит подключи файл `wp-load.php` из текущей директории.
Так вот, вопрос, как подключить этот файл из файла который лежит в папке с темой?
В в файле `config.php` определяется константа:

```
/** Абсолютный путь к директории WordPress. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Но при использовании `require( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' );` выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в require() вместо константы ABSPATH функцию get_template_directory_uri().